# Oracle convert column data type to multiple columns

Tags: oracle, multiple-columns

Hi I have a table containing transactions among multiply parties as following:

```
DATE|FROM|TO|QTY|TYPE
01012020, A, B, 100, LEND
01042020, A, B, 200, LEND
01092020, A, B, 300, LEND
02012020, A, C, 50, LEND
02062020, A, C, 300, LEND
02042020, C, A, 50, REPAY
03042020, D, A, 200, LEND
04062020, A, D, 200, REPAY
```

How can convert above table data to following form?

```
FROM|TO|LEND|REPAY
A, B, 600, 0
A, C, 350, 50
D, A, 200, 200
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are all the possible values in the `TYPE` column known in advance, or do they only become known when we access the data in the table? If they are known in advance, look for "pivoting" - you will find thousands of examples, and your use case is the simplest case of all. If the "types" are only known at runtime, this can't be done with standard SQL; it can be done with dynamic SQL, but that's often a bad idea. Best not to do it at all; alternatively, do it from your reporting software, not in SQL.

Comment: Hi the value in type column is known in advance, for me the tricky part is the query need to smart enough to 'read' the direction of each combination and then put in the right row accordingly. eg for transaction between A and C, if there are record with From = C and To = A with Type = Repay, we need to put it under the From = A and To = C row but in the Repay column, do you mind to share any example for my case above with pivoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with
  sample_data(tx_date, p_from, p_to, qty, tx_type) as (
    select to_date('01012020','ddmmyyyy'), 'A', 'B', 100, 'LEND'  from dual union all
    select to_date('01042020','ddmmyyyy'), 'A', 'B', 200, 'LEND'  from dual union all
    select to_date('01092020','ddmmyyyy'), 'A', 'B', 300, 'LEND'  from dual union all
    select to_date('02012020','ddmmyyyy'), 'A', 'C',  50, 'LEND'  from dual union all
    select to_date('02062020','ddmmyyyy'), 'A', 'C', 300, 'LEND'  from dual union all
    select to_date('02042020','ddmmyyyy'), 'C', 'A',  50, 'REPAY' from dual union all
    select to_date('03042020','ddmmyyyy'), 'D', 'A', 200, 'LEND'  from dual union all
    select to_date('04062020','ddmmyyyy'), 'A', 'D', 200, 'REPAY' from dual
  )
select p_from, p_to, nvl(lend, 0) as lend, nvl(repay, 0) as repay
from   (select case tx_type when 'LEND' then p_from else p_to      end as p_from
             , case tx_type when 'LEND' then p_to   else p_from end as p_to
             , qty, tx_type
        from   sample_data
       )
pivot  (sum(qty) for tx_type in ('LEND' as lend, 'REPAY' as repay))
order  by p_from, p_to   --  or whatever you need to order by
;
P_FROM P_TO         LEND      REPAY
------ ------ ---------- ----------
A      B             600          0
A      C             350         50
D      A             200        200
```

Note that `FROM` is a reserved keyword, and so is `DATE` - I used slightly different column names so they don't clash with SQL keywords.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy, it's work! and in fact i have tried all the solutions, your solution gave the best performance :) Learnt some new things here!

Answer (score 2):

With aggregation for each of the cases of `'LEND'` and `'REPAY'` and then join:

```
SELECT t1."FROM", t1."TO", t1.QTY "LEND", COALESCE(t2."QTY", 0) "REPAY"
FROM (
  SELECT "FROM", "TO", SUM(QTY) QTY 
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE "TYPE" = 'LEND'
  GROUP BY "FROM", "TO"
) t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT "FROM", "TO", SUM(QTY) QTY 
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE "TYPE" = 'REPAY'
  GROUP BY "FROM", "TO"
) t2 ON t1."FROM" = t2."TO" AND t1."TO" = t2."FROM"
ORDER  BY t1."FROM", t1."TO"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=19c14b87e242ca4e386572d91b67d579).
Results:

```
> FROM | TO | LEND | REPAY
> :--- | :- | ---: | ----:
> A    | B  |  600 |     0
> A    | C  |  350 |    50
> D    | A  |  200 |   200
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick response, i have applied the exact same query and able to get the lend part correct but not the repay, which i couldn't get the 0 as expected (this happen to those transactions without repay at all but only lend)

Comment: The row `A,B,100,'LEND'` in your sample data does not have a repay and in my query it is returned as `A,B,100,0`. So the query works as you can see in the demo link I posted.

Comment: This may work for the sample data the OP posted originally. He has now provided more realistic data, where - in particular - there may be multiple `LEND` and `REPAY` transactions between the same persons. This makes the `join` approach unworkable, as it will lead to the same transaction being counted multiple times.

Comment: @mathguy the join can be used also in this case. See my edited answer.

Comment: Right - if you aggregate first, then you join. In any case, this seems more work than is needed, for example because it needs to access the input data twice (compare to the solution in my Answer). If the OP has a small amount of data, this won't matter; if he has a lot of data, it will be interesting if he uses both approaches and he lets us know which worked better on his data.

Comment: Thanks @forpas!! and thanks all too, glad to be here, appreciated all the helps, lots for me to learn here :)

Comment: @forpas your way is probably best way to do in mysql database if we encounter similar scenario in mysql, as mysql doest have pivot option to go by @ mathguy approach, both are very useful and brilliant in a way.

Comment: @Jfrd - pivoting can be done in every database. The **pivot** operator is proprietary to Oracle; the common method of pivoting is conditional aggregation as in Tejash’s answer. There is no need for joining two separate aggregate subqueries against the base table in any db product.

Comment: @mathguy I see what you are saying.. yes agree with this aspect makes sense now, not related to this question -  just I wonder if the values which need to be pivoted the column for example if in in case dynamic then, how would you approach it, in oracle ? We cant give a subquery in 'in' clause right with 'pivot' ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried bit differently using the same DDL and DML that @forpas posted, this approach is also working for me, please test it with more data.

```
select * from 
(select "FROM", "TO", CASE WHEN "TYPE" = 'LEND' then "QTY" end as LEND,
CASE WHEN ( "TYPE" = 'LEND' and lead("TYPE") over (order by "TYPE") <>'REPAY' )  then 0 else "QTY" end as REPAY 
from tablename 
)
where LEND is not null;
```

Comment: HI Thank you for the answer and i have applied the query with my data but seem the REPAY column will always return 0 value.

Comment: Hi, do your table structure have more columns, say like date or the a transaction id in which multiple LEND and REPAY happens ?

Comment: Hi yes, sorry for not given details enough the information, i have edit my questions and sample data which looked more similar to my actual data, yes you are right, the table has datetime and also multiple LEND and REPAY are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and `group by` as follows:

```
SELECT from, to,
       Sum(case when type = 'LEND' then qty else 0 end) as lend,
       Sum(case when type = 'REPAY' then qty else 0 end) as repay 
  From
(Select date, from, to, qty, type from your_table where type = 'LEND'
Union all
Select date, to, from, qty, type from your_table where type = 'REPAY')
Group by from, to
```

Comment: You don't need to read the base table twice (combining the results with `union all`). Instead, you can get the same result in a single pass, using `case` expressions. I show how in my answer. Other than that, my answer is the same as yours, I just use the `pivot` operator instead of conditional aggregation (which in the end is the same thing).